# Fortify Audit Workbench add a comment under Issue summary using command line

Tags: fortify, fortify-source

Fortify seems to have some good command line support to scan and generate a report. Although the utilities do not seem to include an option to add a comment under Issue summary for a particular issue using command line.

Was wondering if there is an option for that and I am just missing seeing it. We audit a bunch of files on a regular basis and it would be quite handy to be able to add comments to a particular issue in a FPR using command line.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You can use the FPRUtility for a buch of things, check SCA guide below. For add comments to FPR file, you can you the Audit Workbench.

https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/fortify-static-code-analyzer-and-tools/1820/SCA_Guide_18.20.pdf